# regex to get any characters including newline until a blank line

Tags: regex

This is the sample:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS Message Log
  Message Log
  Message Log

YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS Message Log
```

I want to get all characters after the timestamp from the first line including all characters of the succeeding line until the blank line?

This is the expected output:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS Message Log
  Message Log
  Message Log
```

I've tried doing something like this:

```
/^(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}) ([^\n]*)/s
```

The first group is the timestamp then the second group I am trying to get all characters including all characters of the succeeding line until the blank line

Comment: I wouldn't use regex for that. What language are you using?

Comment: I am using this for nxlog for a condition.

Here's what I was actually doing:

regex:
`/^(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}) ([^\n]*)/s`

The first group is to capture the timestamp, then in the second group that's the part where I want to get all characters after the timestamp including all characters of the succeeding line until the blank line.

Comment: @MVF If your regex flavor supports lookarounds try: `^(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}) ([\s\S]*?)(?=\n\n|$)` else `^(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}) ([\s\S]*?)(\n\n|$)` or [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pM9yO9/3)

Comment: @Jonny5 I tried your `^(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}) ([\s\S]*?)(?=\n\n|$)` and `^(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}) ([\s\S]*?)(\n\n|$)` but in my json file I see that it captures the all here's the output:
`"Message Log\r\n  Message Log\r\n  Message Log\rn\rnYYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS Message Log"`

Comment: @MVF try to replace the `\n\n` part with `\r?\n\r?\n`

Comment: @Jonny5 You nailed it! `^(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}) ([\s\S]*?)(?=\r?\n\r?\n|$)`

Comment: Glad you got it going @MVF :)

Answer (score 4):

```
^[\s\S]*?(?=\n{2,}|$)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pM9yO9/2

Comment: Here's what I was actually trying to do:

`/^(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2},\d{3}) ([^\n]*)/s`

The first group is to capture the timestamp, then in the second group that's the part where I want to get all characters after the timestamp including all characters of the succeeding line until the blank line.

Comment: @Jonny5 really??ur welcome....do keep `Pune` in ur itinerary.... how do you know chai ? :P

Comment: I love good chai. In Darjeeling had a few cups already few years ago :]

Comment: @Jonny5 Ohh!!!!!!!!dats cool!!!!!!!!! chai + cigarette...dats a routine here for us......just like having water :P

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})([\s\S]+?)\n\n
```

The lines you want are in group 2, the date/time in group 1.

Comment: Here's what I was actually trying to do:

`/^(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2},\d{3}) ([^\n]*)/s`

The first group is to capture the timestamp, then in the second group that's the part where I want to get all characters after the timestamp including all characters of the succeeding line until the blank line.

Comment: @Jonny sorry it should be `/^(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}) ([^\n]*)/s`

Comment: did you missed the `)` for group 1?

Comment: @MVF: Yes, sorry I typed a `(` instead of a `)`.

Comment: @MVF: What doesn't work? What language or editor are you using? May be you have to replace `\n\n` by `\R\R`.

Comment: nope I am using it in nxlog regex condition this is what I did to your code `if $raw_event =~ /(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})([\s\S]+?)\n\n/`